# Use button to setAttribute and display it within span tag

Tags: javascript, html, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to create a real-world example of get and set data attribute.

so I created a simple div that contains the data-email attribute and set a default one.

Now what I want to attain is when I click on the button it will change the default attribute to the set attribute on my JavaScript codes.

Currently I also don't know how can I show the data attribute value inside  tag of my div.

here's my markup:

```
<div id="my-id" data-email="youremail@email.com">Sam's email is <span> "Show Email Here" </span> </div>

<button type="button" id="btn-id" onclick="click-btn()">Set Attribute Now</button>
```

here's my JavaScript:

```
var email = document.getElementById('my-id');

var emailget = email.getAttribute('data-email');
var button = document.getElementById('btn-id');

function click-btn(){
    emailset = email.setAttribute('data-email', newemail@email.com);
}
```

here's the JSFIDDLE link: http://jsfiddle.net/jypb2jdg/6/

Any idea?

Comment: Note that hyphens are not allowed in function names, as hyphens are minus signs in javascript.

Comment: Here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jypb2jdg/13/**

Comment: How about the default value email? how can I show it first hand before updating it via button?

Comment: @KimberlyWright Probably, I'm not understanding, so deleted my answer...

Comment: Why not just write it in the markup instead of `"Show Email Here"`

Comment: If you will look on my markup you'll see a <span> tag. What I want to do is by default dispaly inside the <span> tag the default value of data-email which is "youremail@email.com" now when button was click it will then change to this "newemail@email.com" got it?

Comment: @BhojendraSah - you're close, just remove the hyphen in the function name.

Comment: How hard can it be -> **http://jsfiddle.net/jypb2jdg/14/**

Comment: great answer is there a way instead of using "email.getElementsByTagName" we can use "email.setAttribute" really need to use that on this example.

Comment: Uhm, what? `getElementsByTagName` gets the span, `setAttribute` does something completely different

Comment: Nice answer, how can i set the new value then to newemail.com when i click on the button?

Answer (score 1):

As @adeneo suggested we should not use hyphen in function name as it may be interpreted as minus sign, so remove and you may use like this:

You need to use quote in setAttribute value:

```
function clickBtn(){
    emailset = email.setAttribute('data-email', 'newemail@email.com');
                                               //^^ here           ^^
}
```

---

You need something like this:

```
function clickBtn(){
        emailset = email.setAttribute('data-email', 
                   email.getAttribute('data-email') || 'newemail@email.com');
    }
```

Comment: So how can I show the data attribute value inside span for both the default value and the set value? Is it possible to show me in JSFIDDLE?

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that the email you've written must be within quotes.

```
<div id="my-id" data-email="youremail@email.com">Sam's email is <span id="my-span-id"> "Show Email Here" </span> </div>

<button type="button" id="btn-id" onclick="click_btn()">Set Attribute Now</button>
```

The JS code:

```
function click_btn(){
    var email = document.getElementById('my-id');
    var emailContainer = document.getElementById("my-span-id");
    var emailget = email.getAttribute('data-email');
    emailContainer.innerText = emailget;
    emailset = email.setAttribute('data-email', "newemail@email.com");
}
```

The code can be found in: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jypb2jdg/17/

Some point I want to mention:

- Include the JS before the div. Because button will not recognize click_btn() function before its declaration;
- Do not use '-' symbol for function names in JS.

You could write a script without using ID for span. It will need additional structs (finding child elements, figuring out which one is what you need, set its' innertext.

Comment: Hey you use jQuery i need to use native javascript sorry. If you will look on my markup you'll see a <span> tag. What I want to do is by default dispaly inside the <span> tag the default value of data-email which is "youremail@email.com" now when button was click it will then change to this "newemail@email.com" got it?

Comment: Ok. It can be modified to do that. Just a moment I'll fix it.

Comment: Nice answer just one last thing. How can I show the default data-email value which is "youremail@email.com" dynamically? currently its only showing "Show Email Here" on the span tag.

Comment: Also when I click on the button two times it shows me another email. It must only be just the new email.

Comment: Right, because you've written to change the attribute and I did not delete it. If you remove emailset = email.setAttribute('data-email', "newemail@email.com"); it will not do so.

Comment: If you want to use it using JS then you have to have two JS snippets on before the div another after the div. Because to change the element, element first needs to be exists. To define the onclick event the function must be exist. In JSfiddle it will be hard to do. That's why I recommended jQuery. You can set the properties, define the event dynamically when everything is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep in mind that functions in javascript cannot have hyphens in their name as it is treated as a mathematical operator. Rest is just plain DOM manipulation :

```
<div id='my-id' data-email="youremail@email.com">Sam's email is <span id="mail"> "Show Email Here" </span> 
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn-id" onclick="clickbtn()">Set Attribute Now</button>
```

jS:

```
var em;
window.onload = function(){
  em = document.getElementById("my-id");
  document.getElementById("mail").innerHTML = em.getAttribute("data-email");
};
function clickbtn(){    
  var old_mail = em.getAttribute("data-email");
  em.setAttribute("data-email","newmail");
  document.getElementById("mail").innerHTML = em.getAttribute("data-email");
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dndnqygL/4/

Note : instead of assigning a new id to the span you can also use the `element.firstChild` property to set the `innerHTML`.

Comment: Nice answer just one last thing. How can I show the default data-email value which is "youremail@email.com" dynamically? currently its only showing "Show Email Here" on the span tag. –  Kimberly Wright 5 mins ago   
     
Also when I click on the button two times it shows me another email. It must only be just the new email. –

Comment: When you click it two times, it shows `newmail@email.com`.